# Set Button Size to Content Size in WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I have the following code in WPF XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Hello World" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"></Button>
    </StackPanel>


</Window>
```

I have set the width and height of the Button to "Auto" but still it stretches the complete horizontal width. What am I doing wrong? I do not want to provide a hardcoded values for the width and height!

Comment: try by setting <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left">

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of container control. The `StackPanel` does *not* resize its contents. Try a `Grid` instead:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Also, you don't need to set the `Width` and `Height` to `"Auto"`, as the default values will enable the `Button` to stretch to fill its parent container (depending on the container control). Please see the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more help with the differences between the various container controls in WPF.

Comment: You can also drop the grid and put the button directly as `Window` content.

Comment: I tried to put the Button in Grid but now the Button takes the whole screen instead of the size of the content. Looks like I have to divide the Grid into Rows and Columns.

Comment: Set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` and the button will fit to its content.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasRepiquet HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment are necessary for the above to work. Thanks!

Comment: Your title says *Set Button Size to Content Size* so I assumed that was what you wanted. However, I have now updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow, we have a sore loser here somewhere... care to comment down voter?

Comment: I down voted your answer because it is not related to the type of container but only by the Alignment of the button.I tested it. Your answer partly lead peoples to false information.

Answer (score 6):

As Sheridan said, you do not need to set Width and Height to "Auto".
Your problem is that the default alignment of the StackPanel content is "Stretch".
So just set the HorizontalAlignment property of your button to "Left" or "Right".

Comment: Why, just why is this the default value?

Comment: @Paul: I think the idea is that we normally use StackPanels for situations where we want things to be the same size, and GridPanels for odd-sized components (because GridPanels have more features for aligning them). I'm new to WPF, but I've worked with other layout managers (Qt, Swing and various web ones) and for each of them, it takes a bit of experience to work out how to use them most effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Hello World" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```